# How can I define array of enums in API blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint, mson

My supposed solution for parameters section is

```
+ fields: [firstField, secondField] (array[enum], optional)
  + Members
      + firstField
      + secondField
      + extraField
      + dummyField
```

But it failed on semantic error:

> The example value [firstField, secondField] of parameter fields is not in its list of expected values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to understand your needs and wish for syntax of your API Blueprint.

One of possible solutions in MSON syntax as I see it is probably down below:

```
- fields (array, optional)
    - (enum)
        - firstField
        - secondField
        - extraField
        - dummyField
```

Hope it helps and solves your `Array of Enum` thing.

Comment: This does not work for Parameters, only for Attributes. It seems like the most you can do is specify array[string] as the type, not nest it this much.

Comment: Yes. Parameters are meant to be used for URI Template (Resource URL) definitions.